# unable to create and copy data into volume using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sbt, docker-volume

i am trying to create a volume and copy containers data into it but the `docker volume inspect data-volume` 
is giving me the error

```
[]
Error: No such volume: data-volume:
```

all i am trying to do here is i have three sbt projects `projectA, projectB` and `projectC.` 
`projectB` and `ProjectC` is using the `projectA` jar so i want to create an image of `projectA` and copies the jar of `projectA` to the docker volume, in my case its `data-volume` so that `projectB` and `ProjectC` can use the `data-volume` to get the jar 
here is my `Dockerfile` for `projectA`

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.3_1.2.8_2.13.0

WORKDIR /projectA

ADD . .

RUN sbt publishLocal
```

and here is my `docker-compose.yml` in the parent direcotry of `projectA projectB and projectC`

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  commons:
   build:
    context: ./projectA
   image: projectA-test
   container_name: projectA-container-test
   volumes:
      - data-volume:/root/.ivy2/local/project/project-commons_2.12

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

i have checked the contents of image `projectA-test`

```
docker run --rm -it d73717a5e3b3  bash
```

and checked the folder exited there

```
root@ed351a214093:/# cd /root/.ivy2/local/projectA/projectA-commons_2.12
```

i have two questions here 
Why the volume is not created ?
the approach i am using for the above scenario is it correct or not

Comment: Are the two missing `A`s in the path a spelling error? `.../projectA/projectA...` vs `.../project/project...`

Comment: Volumes are not for code.  Include code or built artifacts like jar files using Dockerfile `COPY` commands.  You can `COPY --from=` another image, or you can build the jar file outside of Docker and include it as a dependency using set.

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose.yml file:

```
  volumes:
    - data-volume:/root/.ivy2/local/project/project-commons_2.12
```

Let's say your compose file is in folder named `my_compose_project`, this the name your compose project will get (unless you override it in `.env`)

The compose project name will be used as a prefix to all object created (containers, networks, volumes)

So, no `data-volume` probably does not exist, but `my_compose_project_data-volume` will. You can see the list of existing volumes with:

```
docker volume ls
```

And inspect that particular volume with

```
docker volume inspect my_compose_project_data-volume
```